# Storing timestamp in joining node value instead of Boolean in Firebase database

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database

Say that I have node `user`, `item` and `user_items` used to join them.

Typically one would`(as advised in official documents and videos)` use such a structure:

```
 "user_items": {
    "$userKey": {
      "$itemKey1": true,
      "$itemKey2": true,
      "$itemKey3": true
    }
  }
```

I would like to use the following structure instead:

```
 "user_items": {
    "$userKey": {
      "$itemKey1": 1494912826601,
      "$itemKey2": 1494912826602,
      "$itemKey3": 1494912826603
    }
  }
```

with values being a timestamp value. So that i can order them by creation date also while being able to tell the associated time. Seems like killing two birds with one stone situation. Or is it?

Any down sides to this approach?

EDIT: Also I'm using this approach for the boolean fields such as: `approved_at`, `seen_at`,... etc instead of using two fields like:

```
"some_message": {
  "is_seen": true,
  "seen_timestamp": 1494912826602,
}
```

Comment: With that structure are you planning of querying using orderByValue().startAt(timeline) ?

Comment: @user7814783 I am using `limitToLast()`. also as suggested by @pajelo below

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can model your database in every way you want, as long as you follow Firebase rules. The most important rule is to have the data as flatten as possible. According to this rule your database is structured correctly. There is no 100% solution to have a perfect database but according to your needs and using one of the following situations, you can consider that is a good practice to do it.

```
1. "$itemKey1": true,
2. "$itemName1": true,
3. "$itemKey1": 1494912826601,
4. "$itemName1": 1494912826601,
```

What is the meaning of `"$itemKey1": 1494912826601,`? Beacause you already have set a `timestamp`, means that your item was uploaded into your database and is linked to the specific user, which means also in other words `true`. So is not a bad approach to do something like this.

Hope it helps.

Comment: My main point was to use just one field instead of using two fields for the same result. Thank you for your input.

Comment: Yes, that's a correct approach. You don't need to use two fields. Only one is enough. Is like "killing two birds with one stone" ;)

Answer (score 1):

Great minds must think alike, because I do the exact same thing :) In my case, the "items" are posts that the user has upvoted. I use the timestamps with `orderBy()`, along with `limitToLast(50)` to get the "last 50 posts that the user has upvoted". And from there they can load more. I see no downsides to doing this.